# $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_o^i\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

Tags: inequality

**Question:** Let $1\leq p<q$ real numbers, $n$ be a positive integer, and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be nonnegative real numbers. Then prove that $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

If $q>1$, $(a+b)^q\geq a^q+b^q$. Therefore, $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^q\right)\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)^{q}$. In other words, if $p=1$, then the inequality is easy. But how can I prove the inequality if $p>1$?

**Edit:** I have tried using a generalized mean, but I am unable to eliminate $w_i$, the weights involved in the function

Comment: How have you tried approaching this problem thus far?

Comment: Also does this help you? [Generalized Mean Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality) Basically, setting $p$ or $q$ as the variable, we would then get the function to be increasing by using partial differentiation.

Comment: @Prometheus Generalized Mean Inequality was the first thing came to my mind but I could not find a way to get rid of weights (I mean $w_i$). I tried to fix $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and show $f: [1,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is nonincreasing

Comment: Can we do that? I thought there is an assumption such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i=1$

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant $w_i = \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $a_i^p$ by $b_i$, denote $q/p=r>1$. Then your inequality becomes

$$\sum b_i\ge \left(\sum b_i^r\right)^{1/r}.$$

You wrote in the OP that this inequality is easy (and it is).